How to trim All Keys in an Array?
I have the potential on creating an Array from reading an Excel spreadsheet that the Column Headers, which will end up as my Array Keys, may have leading and/or trailing spaces.  I'd like to check and trim all my keys in my array.
I tried the following but it did not seem to work
let trimmedKeyData = Object.keys(data).forEach(k => k = k.trim());

If I want to achieve this, I wondered what the best Javascript functions for doing so are?

Please [edit] your question to include some sample data. "did not seem to work" isn't particularly helpful for debugging. You are attempting to use Object methods (Object.keys) on an Array. Also, forEach() doesn't modify the items in place; you should look into use Array.map()

.forEach implicitly returns undefined. You probably want to replace it with .map.

forEach iterates over the array, but returns undefined.  Use map instead:  trimmedKeyData = Object.keys(data).map(k =>k.trim());

Arrays don't have keys, they have indexes. Objects have keys.

It would be better to fix the property names before you create the object.

You can't rename a key in an object. You can delete and re-create a property or create a new object. You may try to do it in the same order as you iterate on it, but the final order is not guaranteed.


var arr = [{
    "COL A   ": 1,
    "COL B   ": 2,
    "COL C": 3,
  },
  {
    "COL A   ": 4,
    "COL B   ": 5,
    "COL C": 6,
  }
]

var newArr = arr.map(function(item) {
  var newItem = Object.keys(item).reduce(function(agg, key) {
    agg[("" + key).trim()] = item[key]
    return agg;
  }, {})
  return newItem
})

console.log(newArr)
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}



